# TEXTAREA maxLength in IE11 Compatibility View

Tags: javascript, html

I'm modifying a web app that currently runs in IE6 and IE8, to run in IE11. Due to large swathes of HTML that does not meet the requirements of Standard Mode in IE11, the website is to run in Compatibility Mode.

One problem I've found is with the value of maxLength for TEXTAREA fields. In the following example, the JavaScript "alert" statement will print the value "350" in IE6, IE8 and IE11 Standard Mode, but gives "undefined" in IE11 Compatibility Mode.

HTML:

```
<TD><TEXTAREA ID="myfield" NAME="myfield" CLASS="clsText" maxLength="350" COLS=120 ROWS=3 STYLE = "WIDTH:620px"></TEXTAREA></TD>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementById(frmCRISLogon.myfield.id);
alert(a.maxLength);
```

Does anyone know why? And is there a way to get the value in IE11 Compatibility Mode? I realise that the proper solution would be to improve the code so that we don't have to use Compatibility Mode, but I'm looking for something I can implement quickly. JQuery is not currently an option.

Comment: What happens if you try `alert(a.getAttribute('maxLength'));`?

Comment: Using getAttribute, it shows the value (350) for IE6, IE8 and IE11 Standard Mode, but "null" for IE11 Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Well it looks like IE7 (that's what IE11 in compatibility mode is) doesn't support maxLength. Does it actually have effect on TextArea, meaning - does it limit user input?

Comment: Yes, the maxLength value is used to limit input in three ways: typing, pasting, and system-modification of the field contents by a spellcheck plug-in.

Comment: No, I mean does this limiting work in IE11 in compatibility mode as well and the only problem is it is not available in JavaScript?

Comment: Ah yes, I see. The limiting does not work in IE11 Compatibility Mode, hence the need to implement in JavaScript, as we do in IE6 and IE8.

Comment: Ok I revised my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When IE11 runs in compatibility mode - it emulates IE7 (to verify this, load http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ while in this mode).

It looks like maxLength attribute is not accessible in IE7 for some reason. You can add some redundancy to make the value accessible in your code.

Add custom attribute that duplicates value of maxLength:

```
<textarea id="myfield" name="myfield" class="clsText" maxlength="350" ml="350" cols=120 rows=3 style="WIDTH:620px"></textarea>
```

Then in your code you can do

```
var a = document.getElementById("myfield");
var maxLength = a.getAttribute("maxLength");

if (maxLength == null) {
   // now you know you're either in IE7 or IExx/compatability mode
   maxLength = a.getAttribute("ml");  // grab value of backup attribute
}
```

This should work universally.